# React - elegant way to re-render just one child component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a table component.  When I scroll left and right on the `<tbody />` I want it to update the xOffset of just the `<theader />` which is in a separate component I'll call `<Header Component />`.  Here's the structure:

```
<Parent Component >
    <Header Component />
    <Very Expensive Body divs/>
    <Very Expensive Body divs/>
    <Very Expensive Body divs/>
</Parent Component >
```

The scroll listener is on the parent component and the xOffset is part of the Parent Component's state.  When I scroll left and right, it also re-renders the very expensive to re-render body components.

What are my options for just the Header Component to re-render?

1) Use Redux and selectors.  Parent component dispatches an xOffset to app state and the `<Header Component />` listens just for that on a selector.  Seems like overkill...

2) I break out all the `<Very Expensive Body Comp divs >` into their own component, and use ShouldComponentUpdate so that it doesn't re-render if everything stays the same besides xOffset.  This doesn't seem like overkill, but I feel like I'm going to be dealing with the same problem because I'll have to put the scroll listener on this new component... and then use the parent component as an intermediary.. oof.

Is there a third more elegant solution?

I'm hoping there's a way to pass a function into the `<Header Component />` so that when the parent component scrolls left and right, it uses that function to update the state of the `<Header Component />` which would cause just it to re-render.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option number 2! Break out your very expensive div tags into their own components and use `shouldComponentUpdate`. Keeping all elements inside one `render()` function does not scale well as you are beginning to see. The whole benefit of using React is that you can create simple, reusable components and build a more complex UI with those. You seem intent on keeping everything inside of one component, but that is essentially an anti-pattern in React.

However, do **not** add a new scroll listener to each component. Instead just keep it on the parent component like you are doing and pass the scroll value down as a prop to all of your new components. If they only need to change after a certain amount of the screen has been scrolled, you can update it in each child's `shouldComponentUpdate` function.

Comment: Hmm you're right I wouldn't have to put a scrollListener on the new component. 
Do you see anything wrong with Option 1 though?

Comment: I would agree with this answer. I didn't really understand this in the OP:

"This doesn't seem like overkill, but I feel like I'm going to be dealing with the same problem because I'll have to put the scroll listener on this new component... and then use the parent component as an intermediary.. oof."

But if this works for your use case, I would go this route.

Comment: @Aaronius sorry should have clarified.  
This table body is inside a component and is scrollable.  I was thinking if I broke out the `<tbody />` into it's own component, I would have to make that component scrollable and not the parent component, and then to communicate between the <tbody> and the <thead> I would have to do it through the parent component.  But I'm thinking I'm wrong about that haha.

Comment: @NateW Redux is a wonderful thing but I generally wouldn't encourage building selectors for app state unless you absolutely can't accomplish what you need by passing down needed data with props. If I understand you correctly, you can just pass down the data. You'll have a much more straightforward app architecture that way. I know when I first started React I just put everything inside 1 or 2 components, but trust me that you only really get the true benefits when you start to make lots of smaller, simple components.

Comment: AndyNoelker and @Aaronius I'm persuaded.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NateW to further expand on that, when you said selector I was assuming you meant using something like the reselect library. It occurs to me that you might have meant making it a connected component. With Redux you need at least one connected component, but I would generally encourage you to make that the most high level component in your app and still pass down the props and use `shouldComponentUpdate` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, one option is to do something like:

```
<Parent Component >
    <Header Component />
    { this.getVeryExpensiveBodyDivs() }
</Parent Component >
```

And have `getVeryExpensiveBodyDivs` generate and cache the divs the first time and then just access them from the cache afterward if they're in the cache. The cache would just be an instance variable (`this.cachedVeryExpensiveBodyDivs`).

Then, in your table component's `componentWillReceiveProps`, you can check if any props are changing that should affect the very expensive body divs. If the prop changes should affect the very expensive body divs, clear the cache. The next time `getVeryExpensiveBodyDivs` is called it will regenerate and recache the divs.

Comment: Innnttteerressting!  Never considered something like that.  Great suggestion!